# Mock WebServerFactoryCustomizer in WebMvc-/SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

Is it possible to mock a [WebServerFactoryCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.webserver.configure) in a SpringBootTest?

```java
public class MyWebServerConfiguration implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<AbstractServletWebServerFactory> {
    @Override
    public void customize(AbstractServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        // Do your thing...
    }
}
```

Why do I do this in the first place? Because I need an additional SSL conext to call a database with an encrypted connection. This means I have 2 connections:

1. The frontend to the users browser
2. The backend to the database

The database uses a certificate, that I create by myself.

One security concern was, that you should be able to do this setup only one time. After that, you're not allowed to change this configuration again. The problem now is, the `@WebMvcTest` or `@SpringBootTest` does call this, for every test. Therefore, I want to replace the production WebServer configuration with a mock one, that does actually nothing. I don't even need the 2 connections. For tests the default SpringBoot configuration would be sufficient enough.

The main problem here is, that this configuration does happen in a very early stage of the Spring livecycle:

> Beware: calls to this interface are usually made from a WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor which is a BeanPostProcessor (so called very early in the ApplicationContext lifecycle). It might be safer to lookup dependencies lazily in the enclosing BeanFactory rather than injecting them with @Autowired.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of MockMVC, is that the HTTP layer is completely skipped. If you use Spring Security, the AuthenticationContext is configured in the test, by binding the Authentication to a thread local variable.
When I want to test test controllers, and the full http stack, I will do use RestTemplate, and make Http request in my test sending the credentials as a http payload, then I'm able to debug the entire auth-chain.

When doing a Sping test, you have the option to use @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.X) where X is RANDOM_PORT, or DEFINED_PORT or MOCK, depending of what level you woant to test at